# Drywall to Shower Liner Junction

Tags: shower, waterproofing

I'm planning on building a shower with a typical plastic shower pan liner: https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/8e45b9f6-39cd-4f9a-ba89-c86cd5071314/svn/oatey-shower-bases-pans-41631-64_1000.jpg. The walls will be water and mold resistant drywall with a roll-on waterproof membrane.

I'm trying to decide how the drywall will meet the plastic shower liner. Should I install the plastic shower pan liner first, then the mold resistant drywall so that water that might get to the drywall will "roll" onto the shower pan liner? Or should I plan on putting up the drywall first, then the shower pan liner taking care to seal the shower pan liner to the drywall so that no water gets between them?

Comment: **The liner IS a waterproof membrane and it will have a bed of mortar and then tile**.   *Precast shower pans with a waterproof membrane  you tile directly onto are also available*.  **More info is needed**.  How are you finishing the shower walls ? will it be tiled. *I use Denshield on shower walls for tile*. **Please  add more details**.  Also do more research and studying so you have a better understanding of the proper steps, ( and there importance ) involved in building a shower. We can help answer questions but you need a solid knowledge base to take on a project like this.

Comment: @Alaskaman Thank you for your comment. I have rewritten the question to keep more directly to the point. Is it better now?

Comment: No mater what kind of shower pan you use it goes in first, Just like in the video you linked to before you edited you question.  Then the walls go on and overlap the pan so that water flowing down the wall runs into the pan. I.E. the pan side walls are behind the shower walls.  You did not answer the question of how the shower walls are to be finished. I would never use drywall for a shower  that is to be tiled. If you are putting in a plastic or fiberglass surround then drywall is ok.

Comment: @Alaskaman Thank you. I am planning to tile. Why do you avoid drywall in that situation?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Gj39ZpwWwmY?t=126 says that caulking will prevent water wicking up the wall, but I'm definitely all ears to hear why not drywall. Thank you again.